# How to add a custom method to Django's Admin Console?

Tags: django

Ok, so in our employee database, we keep a list of all employees and we get this information contained within a data file that is produced by our HR system. The script to truncate the table and populate it with the employee information is done and works nicely. However, I would like the method call to do this from within the application. I thought it would be best to add it to the Admin console since only superusers are allowed to do this. So, is there a way to add a method/link to the console that is not directly model/data related?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the app_index.html admin template (see [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)) and add the url to your view.